# How do I manipulate the size or position of image in jquery using sliding, zooming and cropping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I would like to mimic facebooks banner image upload cropping feature. Currently they allow users to upload a banner but before saving it they cam slide it up or down until their desired portion of the image is showing.

I'd like to do this but also allow zooming and sliding from left to right. I'll store the axis results in the db and use overflow hidden css setting to hide the part of the image outside of the banners div.

Is there a popular plugin for doing this that's light-eight and easy to use available? or is there some tutorial I can follow so I can roll this out by myself?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone that migth find it useful, you could do it with [jQuery Guillotine](http://github.com/matiasgagliano/guillotine). It's similar to Facebook's approach, plus it handles zoom and rotatation.

Check the [demo](http://matiasgagliano.github.io/guillotine).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the links below, which may do for your purposes or at least give you some ideas of what it would take to role your own:

- http://www.dimin.net/software/panojs/
- http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142?ref=lvraa

I would suggest doing some server side manipulation on the image once the user submits it. That way you are not storing/loading very large images when you only need a small part of it. Also, there will be no need for logic to crop/zoom the image each time you load it for display.